# Не могу получить доступ к элементу массива Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Есть код

```
{foreach from=$aPromotions item=promotion}
                {$promotion|@debug_print_var}
            {/foreach}
```

Тут все ок, он возвращает массив

```
Array (12)
id => "75"
name => "Акция13"
type_target => "cats"
cats-id-target => "99,9999"
brands-id-target => ""
id-target => ""
percent => "2"
time-start => "2021-07-05"
time-end => "2021-07-12"
status => "0"
description => "Акция для категорий ..."
tt => Array (0)
```

Получаю доступ к элементу массива в смарти я так

```
{$promotion.name}
{$promotion.type_target}
...и т.д.
```

Тут все ок. Но при попытке получить `{$promotion.time-start|@debug_print_var}`
Я получаю 0

При попытке его вывести, при помощи
`{$promotion.time-start}` - я тоже получаю 0
Что не так то?

======upd===one======

```
{$promotion['time-start']|@debug_print_var}
                {$promotion['time-start']}
```

Не возвращают ничего

Answer (score 0):

У smarty 2 какие-то сложности с доступом к элементам массива, содержащим в т.ч. дефисы. В третьей версии будет работать простой доступ через `{$promotion['time-start']}`, а во второй так не работает. Из найденного на просторах сети - заключить имя поля в переменную и организовать доступ следующим образом

```
{assign var=f value="time-start"}
{$promotion.$f}
```

Также предлагается заменить цикл `{foreach}` на `{section}`.

*ниже написанный вариант ответа, как выяснилось, не актуален для Smarty 2*

не так то, что `-start` это "*минус константа `start`*"
как и в случае с пхп, доступ к членам класса, когда имя поля нестандартное, использовать следует альтернативный вариант записи. В смарти у вас массив, так что обращайтесь как к массиву. Доступ через точку это для упрощения.

```
{$promotion['time-start']}
```

*в случае объектов пхп было бы `$promotion->{"time-start"}`*

Comment: попробовал Ваш совет. вывода просто нет

Comment: просто тогда кагбе вопрос, почему в их доке не указано ничего, на эту тему?
https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.array.indexes

Comment: @Антон а если без кавычек `{$promotion[time-start]}` ?

Comment: то же самое, ничего не выводит

Comment: [тут](https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10112) пишут что вариант - `{assign var=f value="time-start"}` и вывод `{$promotion.$f}`. А вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16422143/1216425) предлагается заменить `foreach` на `section`. Smarty2 уже, конечно, стар как мир. мало у кого он остался, чтобы вообще даже код проверить (у меня нет).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, оформите, пожалуйста коммент - как ответ, вопрос правда почему в доке (ссылку я сбрасывал) - этого нет - открыт))

Comment: @Антон а у вас там точно массив, а не объект?

Comment: вар дамп же пишет что arrray

Comment: пишет `debug_print_var` а не `var_dump`, что у него внутри я понятия не имею. Вам как разработчику должно быть уж виднее, что там передается в шаблон, объекты или массивы, поэтом и уточнил.

Comment: я за вар дамп со стороны php говорил)